# How to use SUBSTRING using REGEXP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, substring

I have situation, where I have to substring regular expression from description using MySQL.

Descritpion:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac magna
>   enim, eu adipiscing sapien. Cras lacinia vulputate elit, sed
>   adipiscing felis interdum a. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
>   dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus sit amet ante
>   orci. **D9801** Quisque dignissim posuere quam, id suscipit nisl
>   scelerisque nec.

Where **D9801** is REGEXP. Every description has different content but my reg exp should looks like: `REGEXP 'D[[:digit:]]{4}'`

I know the REGEXP return only true/false value, but how can I make query to return only **D9801** value?

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING (description, LOCATE(REGEXP 'D[[:digit:]]{4}', description), 5)
FROM (
   SELECT "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac magna enim, eu adipiscing sapien. Cras lacinia vulputate elit, sed adipiscing felis interdum a. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus sit amet ante orci. **D9801** Quisque dignissim posuere quam, id suscipit nisl scelerisque nec." AS description
) temp
```

but now I know this is totally wrong...
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Is the length of the code `D9801` constant in all the cases?

Comment: Yes always REGEXP has "d" at the beginning and "xxxx" - 4 digits at the end: Dxxxx

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't provide this function. But you can check out [udf](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp).

Take a close look at this function : `REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,mode]]])`

Comment: I'm using OVH hosting and I think I cannot use any UDF.